# How to Auto Download File When User Opened The Site

Tags: web

I'm Kurdish . I'm Not Know All English Language

But I Have One Question:

I went to create a site but How to auto download the file when user open the site, without going through the "save as" ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly get your Question.
But I think This Link might help you.

[LINK (download-file-using-javascript-jquery) !](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery)